# npm install not working on windows with git dependencies

Tags: node.js, git, npm

So, in my package.json I have, in dependencies, besides some npm modules, some private git repositories from my company:

```
devDependencies": {
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "build-tools": "git+ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/repo.git#master",
    "chai": "^1.9.2",
    "download": "^0.2.1",
    .....
}
```

If i run npm install, it's working almost everywhere.
We mostly use Macs, but there's also another colleague running `gitbash on windows` and he has no problems with it.
I have a colleague with the same setup, `windows and gitbash`, that when we try to run `npm install` he gets the error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```

Also, when we change `#master` to `#commit-sha`  npm installs successfully, so it's not a problem with authentication or whatever.

He is running Git for windows 1.9.4 and npm@latest (2.2.0).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently cleaning up the `npm-cache` in the `[USER]\AppData\Roaming\` folder, then re-installing `npm` fixes the problem.